# Need help with solution on a physics calculation involving newtonian mechanics - (angular momentum)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, home-experiment, perpetual-motion

I have been looking into conservation of energy in association with angular momentum (or in simple terms perpetual-motion-machines).

Specifically need an answer to the following -

Let's say there is a wheel/rim with a single bar along its diameter.
The radius is 100m. There are weights of 1kg each at the end of each diameter.

Thus the system is in equilibrium.

I now apply torque force to the above system (similar to that applied on a car's wheels by its axle) by suspending a 40kg weight on a friction-less pulley. The pulley's diameter is 5m.

I am trying to figure out how fast the wheel would accelerate after 't' seconds.

My understanding is that the system involving the 100m wheel with 1kg weights on its rim along the diameter - is equivalent to a system involving a 2kg weight on a table (and on frictionless rollers) and is linked to the 40kg weight over a frictionless pully my means of a tether/string.

So from the following link -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DD3zh0_L0M

I've calculated (assuming gravity to be 10 m/s) that it would be 1.772 by the time the pully effectively turns 90 degrees and has a velocity (and consequently the larger wheel turns 90 degrees implying that both masses m-wheel-lhs and m-wheel-rhs are at 157 m/s approx at that point.

The numbers i've used -

```
m-wheel-lhs=1kg    
m-wheel-rhs=1kg    
r-wheel=100m    
r-pulley=5m    
m-pulley=40kg (20+20)

Momentum of m-wheel-lhs = 1 * 100 = 100
Momentum of m-wheel-rhs = 1 * 100 = 100
Momentum of m-pulley  = 5 * 40 = 200
```

Also I've assumed the angle between the weight on the table and the one over the frictionless pulley to be 90 degrees. Thus that component of the weight is zero. This yeilds an acceleration that is half of what is normal.

https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/free-fall?c=INR&v=v_0:0!ms,g:5!mps2!l,h:7.85!m

Is the above calculation correct?

PS : If yes, then it appears to violate the law of conservation of energy ( 157 meters would imply that the two weights can reach a height of 1233m).

If not what is the step in the above calculation that needs to be corrected?

Below is an illustration of what I've tried to explain above.

[image]

#Update-01 -

As part of addressing 'generality' criteria (for being on-topic as per the sites' guidelines), the question could be rephrased as -

1. Am I correct to interpret the system above the 'yellow' line as the one below to it?
2. Although it involves rotation, I have considered it in linear terms itself owing to the fact that this is precisely what radians are based out of. In any case, what would be the forces or concepts that I would need to apply such that law of conservation holds - in addition to or as an alternate to what I've considered ?

#Update-02 -
Significantly, it appears that one would need to consider moment-of-inertia (usually denoted as ***I*** , and has a value of M.R<sup>2</sup> for a point object of mass **M** at a distance **R** from a pivot point) - which I had chosen to ignore.
However leaving the question unchanged otherwise since a cross-validation would never the less be of much help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve properly a problem in mechanics, it is strongly advised to follow these steps:

- Clearly identify the system and the frame of reference:

  - System: Wheel+pulley_mass.
  - Reference frame: the road.
- If the system is not rigid, consider your system as a collection of rigid
  subsystems.

  - Wheel
  - pulley
  - Hanging mass.
    To simplify, I join the two subsystems into a single Pulley-mass.
- Try to visualize the dynamics of one subsystem at the time.

  - Wheel: rotates + moves to the right.
  - Pulley: rotates
  - mass m: accelerates down **AND** to the right.
- Correct your graph accordingly:

  - The string holding m is tilted to the left due to the acceleration of
    the whole system to the right.
- List all the forces acting on each subsystem.

  - Wheel: $ \overrightarrow{N} , M_{wheel} \overrightarrow{g}, M_{wheel} \overrightarrow{g}$
  - Pulley_mass: $ m\overrightarrow{g}, -\overrightarrow{T}$
- List all the torques acting on each subsystem.

  - Wheel:$\overrightarrow{\tau}$
  - pulley_mass:$-\overrightarrow{\tau}$
- List all the constraints.

  - Wheel: rolling without slipping: $ V_{wheel}=R_{wheel}\Omega_{wheel}$
  - pulley_mass: $ v_{m}=r_{pulley}~\omega_{pulley}$
  - Liaison: $ \Omega_{wheel}=\omega_{pulley}$
- Identify the velocities and reference frame for each subsystem:

  - Wheel: reference frame= road.
  - pulley_mass: reference frame =road.  $ \overrightarrow{v}_{m/road}= 
     \overrightarrow{v}_{m/wheel}+ 
     \overrightarrow{v}_{wheel/road}= \overrightarrow{v_{m}} + \overrightarrow{V}_{wheel} $
- Apply Newton's laws to each subsystem or conservation of energy.
  $$(\frac{1}{2} I \omega ^{2}+ \frac{1}{2} M_{wheel+masses}V_{wheel}^{2})+ ( \frac{1}{2}m~(\overrightarrow{v_{m}} + \overrightarrow{V}_{wheel})^{2}+ \frac{1}{2} I_{pulley} \omega^2+mgh)=E_{initial}$$
- List all the unknowns and count the number of equations. They should be equal.

  - $\omega$,$~~ x_{wheel}$, y(m),$~~\theta$: the angle of the rope with the vertical.

Comment: What road are you talking about? There's no mention of a road in the question.

Comment: @ PM 2ring The road is the reference frame.

Comment: @Shaktyai - Thank you for respnding. Basically, I had chosen to, rather conveniently, skip considering moment-of-inertia (which, for a point object is `M*R*R` and you have mentioned as `I`). Believe that to be the explanation that I was looking for - although I am still looking for the exact answer.